# Color picker using uisetcolor - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to do a color picker in Matlab 2020b using this line `c = uisetcolor`. I have two questions that an assistance will be appreciated:

1. When I run the code I get the default image (A) but I wish that it will automatically appear like in B, is it possible to do/set it via programming?
2. How can I get directly the output in RGB [0-255] scale? (I know that I can do the ratios to the RGB [0-1] scale output that I get)

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to include your MATLAB version? Older versions (2017b tested) do not even have that option